# What is the use of auto?

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand we can use `auto` like:

```
auto a = 1;
auto b = Foo(1,2);
```

Or in the function call:

```
auto foo(){
  return Foo(1,2);
}
```

But C++11 also provides uniform initialization and initialization list, so we can do:

```
Foo a {1,2};
Foo b = {1,2};
Foo foo(){
  return {1,2};
}
```

So what is the use of `auto` if we already have braces syntax? (except define a primitive type)

Comment: Trivial example: `auto it = v.begin()` where `v` is some container of type `T` in a deduced context.

Comment: Take a look at [Herb Sutter's "AAA-style" article](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Comment: Using `auto` to deduce the return type of a function is a C++1y feature. In C++11, there's only the trailing-return-type `auto foo() -> Foo;` feature (and return type deduction for simple lambdas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto` is best for templates and iterators.

Not only it can really simplify the syntax and improve code readability, but it can also obsolete some extensive template usage.

Check out [this guy's page](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html) - very nice and to the point.

Conciser the following:

```
template <typename BuiltType, typename Builder>
void makeAndProcessObject (const Builder& builder) {
    BuiltType val = builder.makeObject();
    // ...
}
```

Now with `auto` you can get rid of the multiple types in the template:

```
template <typename Builder>
void makeAndProcessObject (const Builder& builder)
{
    auto val = builder.makeObject();
    // ...
}
```

Moreover, when you actually call this function, you don't need to provide any type as a template parameter:

```
MyObjBuilder builder;
makeAndProcessObject(builder);
```

Comment: This could also be solved easily without auto. Namely with `typedef`s. Though one can consider `auto` more elegant others might consider `typedef`s better as it manifests the relationship between `Builder` and `BuiltType` in code. Besides this the two snippets arent equivalent: You cant create(/default construct) an object of type `BuiltType` in the below snippet without calling `makeObject()`. In the above example it would be possible.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best use of `auto` can be seen when you use it with the good ol' iterators. Compare:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
```

to:

```
for (auto it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
```

Even though, in C++11 we have range-fors that helps out a lot better, iterators are still widely used in cases where your range is not well defined or you need to perform action on the elements.

In general, `auto` can be useful when a type, that is a PITA to type, can be automatically inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

When the return type is *unspecified* you need auto. For example, `std::bind`.

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
int n = 7;
auto f1 = std::bind(f, _2, _1, 42, std::cref(n), n);
```

Comment: Also, lambda-expressions. You *could* use `decltype` to get the type of a `bind`-expression, but that doesn't work for lambdas, as the type of *each* lambda-expression is unique (and they may not appear as unevaluated operands IIRC).